# How to get user current location WOEID

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

I'm currently working on a project that makes use of [simpleweather.js](http://simpleweatherjs.com) and in order to get a certain locations weather conditions you have to send a WOEID to the method.

I was wondering if there might not be some type of service or something that I can use, instead of explicitly having to set the [WOEID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOEID) in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but if anybody else finds it, simpleWeather.js now supports passing in lat/long coordinates vs just a woeid.